# Issues with xsl for-each statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having another issue with XSL statements. I'm trying to add in a conditional so that if a certain value is found, in this instance 'call' then it behaves slightly differently. I know it's a simple thing I'm doing wrong but no idea what!

Basically in the code below is seems to return the correct Boolean value however it carries on and puts the call cost wording in still. The class and URL location are both output correctly.

Thanks in advance!

XML

```
<rhs_options>
<title>RHS title</title>
<service>
    <option>call</option>
    <text>telephone number text</text>
    <telephone>telephone number</telephone>
    <link>telephone number link</link>
</service>
<service>
    <option>branch</option>
    <text>branch text</text>
    <telephone/>
    <link>branch link</link>
</service>
<service>
    <option>online</option>
    <text>online text</text>
    <telephone/>
    <link>online link</link>
</service>
```

XSL

```
<aside class="cta">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='RHS_Options']/rhs_options/title"/></h4>
    <xsl:for-each select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='RHS_Options']/rhs_options/service">  
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='RHS_Options']/rhs_options/service/option='call'">
                <p class="{./option}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./text"/>
                        <br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./telephone"/>
                        <br/>
                    <a href="{./link}">
                        Call charges
                    </a>
                </p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="/Properties/Data/Datum[@ID='ID1']/DCR[@Type='RHS_Options']/rhs_options/service/option='phone'or'online'">
                <p class="{./option}">
                    <a href="{./link}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./text"/>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I've also tried to change the last <xsl:when> for a <xsl:otherwise> but it made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You want**:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="option='call'">
            <p class="{option}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
                    <br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="telephone"/>
                    <br/>
                <a href="{link}">
                    Call charges
                </a>
            </p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="option='phone' or option = 'online'">
            <p class="{option}">
                <a href="{link}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
                </a>
            </p>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

**Explanation**:

The problem of the provided code is that *absolute* XPath expressions are used but it is necessary to use *relative* Xpath expressions.

**Certainly, it is better *not* to use `xsl:for-each* and *not* to use any explicit XSLT conditional instructions**.

Here is code that is equivalent but much more compact and maintainable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <aside class="cta">
        <h4><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h4>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </aside>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="service[option='call']">
   <p class="{option}">
     <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
     <br/>
     <xsl:value-of select="telephone"/>
     <br/>
     <a href="{link}">
      Call charges
     </a>
   </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="service">
   <p class="{option}">
     <a href="{link}">
       <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
     </a>
   </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<rhs_options>
    <title>RHS title</title>
    <service>
        <option>call</option>
        <text>telephone number text</text>
        <telephone>telephone number</telephone>
        <link>telephone number link</link>
    </service>
    <service>
        <option>branch</option>
        <text>branch text</text>
        <telephone/>
        <link>branch link</link>
    </service>
    <service>
        <option>online</option>
        <text>online text</text>
        <telephone/>
        <link>online link</link>
    </service>
</rhs_options>
```

**the wanted result is produced:**

```
<aside class="cta">
   <h4>RHS title</h4>RHS title<p class="call">telephone number text<br/>telephone number<br/>
      <a href="telephone number link">
      Call charges
     </a>
   </p>
   <p class="branch">
      <a href="branch link">branch text</a>
   </p>
   <p class="online">
      <a href="online link">online text</a>
   </p>
</aside>
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much. It makes it so much clearer!